# Enable search for hidden columns in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have bunch of hidden columns in my jqGrid, on which I want to enable search,

eg.

```js
{ name: 'Col1', width: 200, hidden: true, search: true },
{ name: 'Col2', width: 200, hidden: true, search: true },
{ name: 'Col3', width: 200, hidden: true, search: true }
```

But this columns not displaying search popup.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use additional [searchhidden](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) option in the column definition:

```js
searchoptions: {searchhidden: true}
```

Comment: Hey Oleg, I have 1 more query, sorting is not working in formatted column. I mean in column , I have concatted 2 columns Date and its time, its displaying fine , but its doing nothing at the time of sort.

Comment: @DotNetIsMyPower: Everything is possible, but one have to know implementation details. I suggest that you open new question and include the code which you use. The test data are also helpful.

Comment: yup right , Everything is possible, and I got its solution :-)